# MySQL and Firebase kept in sync with NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, firebase

Note: This is not about a question about migrating from MySql this is a question about keeping a MySQL database synced up with Firebase nicely.

Hi folks,

I am currently trying to build a web app with a MySQL database locally and a Firebase that will be used to update the client in real time.

I am looking at an app that has a similar structure and wondering if the way it is structured is idiomatic or even makes sense.

In short:

1. The Node server launches and pushes a huge Javascript object which contains the MySQL schema up to Firebase. This is done through a sequences of SQL queries as promises.
2. On the client side there are Angular directives that push updates to the schema when different clients make different requests. This updates the local storage (the mySQL database) and after this a request is made to update the Firebase with the the new parameters inserted into the database.

This seems to work be feels very sloppy to me. Specifically pushing the huge database object up Firebase does not seem very performant. Am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry, what problem really you trying to solve? On a high level.

Comment: Firebase is a NoSQL database that supports real-time synchronization to connected clients. Using Firebase as a caching/messaging layer on top of another database sounds like a bad idea to me. If you just want messaging, use a dedicated messaging solution. If you want a real-time synchronizing database, use Firebase.

Comment: @SergeyYarotskiy in short I am working with a SQL database that already exists. I am creating an app that will be accessing this database's data and periodically updating some of the values. However, some of this data needs to be updated in real time and sent to many clients. An example of this is a check-in function. Where a user can check in and an agent can view in real time that the user has checked in.

Comment: Ok, but you mentioned here nodejs. Sorry, I still dont understand why to use Firebase. Maybe better to use socket.io - update values in db and then just send notifications for all connected clients? Thats what websockets been designed for. And no need for additional storage at all.

Comment: I went through the same exercise not to long ago and at the end, I removed SQL from the project completely. I dumped my data to flat files and then worked up some code to 'import' it into Firebase, created references amongst the data and updated code to handle it accordingly. The move took time up front by has saved countless hours on the backend. It's something you may want to consider if possible.